# Remove white space wrapping from React-pdf

Tags: css, reactjs, react-pdf, react-pdfrenderer

I am trying to generate a single line of text without wrapping text further down the page or breaking into a new line. My page width is dynamic as well, it is calculating the width of the element and then setting the generated PDF width. For example: "This is quite the long sentence", outputs into:

"This is
quite the
long sentence"
 When it should just be one continuous line. It doesn't seem like `whiteSpace: nowrap` is supported ([documentation](https://react-pdf.org/styling)), so I'm not sure what a good work around could be.

```
//Calculate Element Width
const getElSize = () => {
const newWidth = ref.current.offsetWidth;
setWidth(newWidth);
console.log(width);
};

useEffect(() => {
getElSize();
}, [input]);

//PDF Output
const MyDoc = () => {
        return (
            <Document>
                <Page
                    size={{ width: width + 200 }}
                    style={{
                        fontFamily: pdfFont,
                        fontSize: textSize,
                    }}
                >
                    <View style={{ lineHeight: "0" }}>
                        <Text>{input}</Text>
                    </View>
                </Page>
            </Document>
        );
    };
```